# Send gcm message to only installed user

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I want to send gcm mesage to only installed user or devices.

Active (installed) user is only 20% of gcm-registerred users in my app.

Maybe 7~80% is delete my app.

I want to send ony installed users, not uninsatlled user.

It is possible to send to only installed users? or to get event that user uninstall my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send your message to all users. If a user has uninstalled the app, GCM will notify you in reply to your push message. You can then remove those users from the database.
You can see a description of this process [here](http://support.airbop.com/kb/faq/how-does-gcm-handle-app-uninstalls)

1. The end user uninstalls the application.
2. The 3rd-party server sends a message to GCM server.
3. The GCM server sends the message to the device.
4. The GCM client receives the message and queries Package Manager about whether there are
   broadcast receivers configured to receive it, which returns false.
5. The GCM client informs the GCM server that the application was uninstalled.
6. The GCM server marks the registration ID for deletion.
7. The 3rd-party server sends a message to GCM.
8. The GCM returns a NotRegistered error message to the 3rd-party server.
9. The 3rd-party deletes the registration ID.

Answer (score 1):

if you send gcm message then only install user get this any user who have alredy uninstall your app not get nofication dear

try to send to all user its not an problem

Comment: I know. Uninstalled devices cannot revice message. They does not have receiver. But I want to reduce time for sending gcm message.